# jquery modal dialog only shows once

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I know there are multiple posts on this but I still can't get it right.  I've tried so many combinations.  I'm trying to create a dialog box when you click a button.  Inside the dialog box is a form but that is not important for now.  I can get the dialog to show up once but not on the second click.  Here is what I have right now:

```
var $dialog = $('#cameraform').dialog({
    modal:true,
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable:false,
    width: 625,
    close: function() {
        $(this).remove();
    }
}); //init dialog

//events            
$('.addwebcam').click(function(e) {
    $dialog.dialog('open');
});
```

HTML:

```
<button class="addwebcam">Add Webcam</button>
<div id="cameraform" title="Add a camera">
...//my form
</div>
```

I've also tried initializing the dialog in the click event but that doesn't work at all. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: try providing a demo on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: what if you change `[...]close: function() { $(this).remove(); } [...]` to `[...]close: function() { $dialog.dialog('close'); } [...]`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jaspermogg/tbsuh/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/tbsuh/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't this line of code

> $(this).remove();

removing your dialog box from the DOM?

I'd think to close the dialog, you'd use:

> $( this ).dialog( "close" );

Comment: Geez, didn't even look at that. But now it won't close the dialog at all. But the fiddle seems to work okay.